# Recursive Boolean method to check if integer is divisible

Tags: java, recursion

This is what i have so far, it works, but its not recursive. Any idea how to translate this into recursion

```
   public static boolean isDivide(int n)
   {
   if (n < 10) System.out.println (n);
   int sum = 0;
   while (n > 0)
   {
   sum += n % 10;
   n = n / 10;
   }
   while (sum >= 0)
   {
   sum -=3;
   }
   //System.out.println(n==0);
   return n==0;

   }
```

Comment: You also have a mod operation when calculating the sum

Comment: Seems like you're missing the math foundation here - a number is divisible by 3 if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by 3. You can apply that logic recursively.

Comment: please use closures... and `if(codition);` does nothing with a semicolon

Comment: @Philipp There are no if statements like that here, and closures have no relation to this question at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static boolean isDivisibleBy3(int n)
{
    if(n == 0) return true;
    if(n < 0) return false;
    return isDivisibleBy3(n - 3);
}
```

for n >= 0. 
If you need to check negative numbers:

```
public static boolean isDivisibleBy3(int n) {
    if(n == 0) return true; 
    if(n == -1 || n == -2 || n == 1 || n == 2) return false; 
    if (n < 0) return isDivisibleBy3(n + 3); 
    else return isDivisibleBy3(n - 3); 
}
```

Comment: Makes sense to me now!

Comment: @AshwinP sorry, its my fault, now program works fine

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to replace while loops with tail end recursions. For recursion, you need two things: a general case, and a base case. The base case is usually easier, so it's best to start with that. What's the simplest possible input this program can get? It's 0-3. So here's the base case:

```
public static boolean isDivide(int n)
{
    if(n==0||n==3)
        return true;
    else if(n==1||n==2)
        return false;
```

For this, the general case is also pretty easy. For any n that is divisible by 3, so is n-3.  So we can just call the same function on n-3.

```
    else
        return isDivide(n-3);
}
```

And you're done!